# JetBrains Rider not detecting mono or Unity API

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ubuntu, mono, rider

I'm trying to make JetBrains Rider 2020.3 work properly on Ubuntu 20.04.2. I have installed mono and dotNet following links from this site (https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207335749-Using-Project-Rider-under-Linux-prerequisites).

Rider detects mono, .net CLI and MSBuild 16, but when I create new 'Console Application' Rider can't even recognize 'System' namespace.

This is my console output for the dependencies.

```
~> dotnet --list-sdks
5.0.201 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]
~> mono --version
Mono JIT compiler version 6.8.0.105 (Debian 6.8.0.105+dfsg-2 Wed Feb 26 23:23:50 UTC 2020)
Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
        TLS:           __thread
        SIGSEGV:       altstack
        Notifications: epoll
        Architecture:  amd64
        Disabled:      none
        Misc:          softdebug
        Interpreter:   yes
        LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
        Suspend:       hybrid
        GC:            sgen (concurrent by default)
~> dotnet --version
5.0.201`
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

I had to add

```
export FrameworkPathOverride=/usr/lib/mono/4.5/
```

to `.xprofile` file due to SDK bug.

Comment: Where is this `.xprofile` located?